# CS50 - Issue with pset4 filter "blur"

Tags: c, filter, blur, cs50

My blur function is behaving oddly. I've recreated the 3x3 bitmap from check50 to get more approximate results from my tests but, for some reason, every right or lower edge pixels are not working properly.

While debugging, I've found that, for some reason, my for loops are not behaving properly. I'll show my code and an example below.

Code:

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width]; // Declares temporary structure to avoid overwriting of original values while running loops

    // For loop to set the value of i, rows or height
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // For loop to set the value of j, columns or width
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            float counter = 0.0;
            int sumRed = 0;
            int sumGreen = 0;
            int sumBlue = 0;

            // For loop to set the value of k, to get surrounding pixels
            for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++)
            {
                for (int m = -1; m < 2; m++)
                {
                    if ((i - k) >= 0 && (i - k) < height && (j - m) >= 0 && (j - m) < width)
                    {
                        sumRed = sumRed + image[i - k][j - m].rgbtRed; // Adds the value of verified pixel to the sum
                        sumGreen = sumGreen + image[i - k][j - m].rgbtGreen;
                        sumBlue = sumBlue + image[i - k][j - m].rgbtBlue;
                        counter++; // To get the average
                    }
                }
            }

            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sumRed / counter); // Sets new color based on average of surrounding pixels
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / counter);
            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sumBlue / counter);
        }
    }

    // Start new loops to switch original values with temp values
    for (int i = 0; i < height - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width - 1; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = temp[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temp[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temp[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

And here's the
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pBfU.png).

As an example of what I've found during the debug, let's say that:

```
i = 0
j = 2
k = 0
m = 0
```

Here, instead of `sumRed` getting the value of `image[0 - 0][2 - 0] (RGB 70, 80, 90)`, it's getting the values from `image[2][2] (RGB 240, 250, 255)`.

I've not yet tested the other error cases, but I suppose something similar is happening there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code would be easier to read if you used `row` and `col` instead of `i` and `j`.

Comment: It might be better if `counter` were an `int`. Then, do: `round((double) sumRed / counter)`, But, the output cell is only eight bits. You may need: `sumRed = round((double) sumRed / counter); temp[i][j].rgbtRed = (sumRed < 255) ? sumRed : 255;` This is saturation math. Otherwise, when you assign to an 8 bit cell, it's modulo math, equivalent to `sumRed % 256`. That would yield `257 --> 1` (nearly black) instead of `257 --> 255` (bright red)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is prefaced by my top comment:

> It might be better if `counter` were an `int`. Then, do: `round((double) sumRed / counter)`, But, the output cell is only eight bits. You may need: `sumRed = round((double) sumRed / counter); temp[i][j].rgbtRed = (sumRed < 255) ? sumRed : 255;` This is saturation math. Otherwise, when you assign to an 8 bit cell, it's modulo math, equivalent to `sumRed % 256`. That would yield `257 --> 1` (nearly black) instead of `257 --> 255` (bright red)

Your biggest problem is that your convolution kernel index calculations are incorrect.

Instead of:

```
(i - k)
(j - m)
```

You want:

```
(i + k)
(j + m)
```

Also, your the limits on your final loops to copy back from `temp` to `image` are off by 1.

Plus, I'd use more descriptive variables. And, your code can be simplified a bit. Here's a refactored version that incorporates the bug fixes:

```
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char rgbtRed;
    unsigned char rgbtGreen;
    unsigned char rgbtBlue;
} __attribute__((__packed__)) RGBTRIPLE;

// Blur image
void
blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Declares temporary structure to avoid overwriting of original values
    // while running loops
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
#if 1
    RGBTRIPLE *tmp;
    RGBTRIPLE *img;
#endif

    // For loop to set the value of yctr, rows or height
    for (int yctr = 0; yctr < height; yctr++) {
        // For loop to set the value of xctr, columns or width
        for (int xctr = 0; xctr < width; xctr++) {
#if 0
            float counter = 0.0;
#else
            int counter = 0;
#endif
            int sumRed = 0;
            int sumGreen = 0;
            int sumBlue = 0;

            // For loop to set the value of yoff, to get surrounding pixels
            for (int yoff = -1; yoff < 2; yoff++) {
// NOTE/BUG: this is the main bug
#if 0
                int ycur = yctr - yoff;
#else
                int ycur = yctr + yoff;
#endif
                if (ycur < 0)
                    continue;
                if (ycur >= height)
                    continue;

                for (int xoff = -1; xoff < 2; xoff++) {
// NOTE/BUG: this is the main bug
#if 0
                    int xcur = xctr - xoff;
#else
                    int xcur = xctr + xoff;
#endif
                    if (xcur < 0)
                        continue;
                    if (xcur >= width)
                        continue;

                    // Adds the value of verified pixel to the sum
                    tmp = &image[ycur][xcur];
                    sumRed += tmp->rgbtRed;
                    sumGreen += tmp->rgbtGreen;
                    sumBlue += tmp->rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;      // To get the average
                }
            }

            // Sets new color based on average of surrounding pixels
            tmp = &temp[yctr][xctr];

#if 0
            tmp->rgbtRed = round(sumRed / counter);
            tmp->rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / counter);
            tmp->rgbtBlue = round(sumBlue / counter);
#else

            sumRed = round((double) sumRed / counter);
            tmp->rgbtRed = (sumRed < 255) ? sumRed : 255;

            sumGreen = round((double) sumGreen / counter);
            tmp->rgbtGreen = (sumGreen < 255) ? sumGreen : 255;

            sumBlue = round((double) sumBlue / counter);
            tmp->rgbtBlue = (sumBlue < 255) ? sumBlue : 255;
#endif
        }
    }

    // Start new loops to switch original values with temp values
// NOTE/BUG: the for loop ranges are incorrect
#if 0
    for (int yctr = 0; yctr < height - 1; yctr++) {
        for (int xctr = 0; xctr < width - 1; xctr++) {
            image[yctr][xctr].rgbtRed = temp[yctr][xctr].rgbtRed;
            image[yctr][xctr].rgbtGreen = temp[yctr][xctr].rgbtGreen;
            image[yctr][xctr].rgbtBlue = temp[yctr][xctr].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
#endif

#if 0
    for (int yctr = 0; yctr < height; yctr++) {
        for (int xctr = 0; xctr < width; xctr++) {
            image[yctr][xctr] = temp[yctr][xctr];
        }
    }
#endif

#if 1
    tmp = &temp[0][0];
    img = &image[0][0];

    int idxlim = width * height;
    for (int idxcur = 0; idxcur < idxlim; idxcur++)
        img[idxcur] = tmp[idxcur];
#endif
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, I've learned some new ways to structure code from it, so much appreciated. A question, though: I've thought and tried changing the operator before asking here, but since the range of the `yoff` and `xoff` goes from -1 to 1, `int xcur = xctr - xoff` would result in `{1, 0, -1}`, while `int xcur = xctr + xoff` would result in `{-1, 0, 1}`. Shouldn't that bring the same results?