# How do I access neighboring values in a 2D Array?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I'm trying to create a box blur effect for a given test "pixel".

In the commented section below I'm looking for a way to generate the newblock by taking the average of the neighboring blocks. What I'm having difficulty with is accessing the neighboring blocks.

I'm trying to avoid a third for loop inside the 2 for loops already, but maybe that's the only way to do it? Looking for guidance on what's a better solution, not a outright code solution.

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    short int red;
    short int green;
    short int blue;
} pixel;

int main(void)
{
    pixel block[3][3];

    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
            block[row][col].red = 10;
            block[row][col].green = 10;
            block[row][col].blue = 10;
        }
    }

    //Given block, for each pixel, find the average of the values of all of the pixels that are within 1 row and column of the original pixel
    for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
            pixel newblock;

            /* 

            The task is to generate the newblock values of r g and b
            printf("Row-1: %i, Row+1: %i\n", row-1, row+1);
            printf("Col-1: %i, Col+1: %i\n", col-1, col+1);

            newblock.red = 20;
            newblock.green = 20;
            newblock.blue = 20;

            */

            block[row][col].red = newblock.red;
            block[row][col].green = newblock.green;
            block[row][col].blue = newblock.blue;

            //printf("(R: %i, G: %i, B: %i)\t", block[row][col].red, block[row][col].green, block[row][col].blue);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just add up the values of the surrounding blocks? `block[row-1][col-1] + block[row][col-1] ...  / numBlocks`

Comment: You _do_ need a third loop. And, you need a separate output array. Otherwise, instead of taking _original_ pixel values as input to the blur filter, some will be already blurred [as you progress from pixel to pixel]. The usual is, for a given pixel `P[y][x]`, you take the average of the sum of 3x3 box around the pixel (e.g. `sum / 9`). See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394007/cs50-issue-with-pset4-filter-blur/61395136#61395136