# I need help fixing this Segmentation fault error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I am trying to implement the sobel edge detection algorithm in C using a function called 'edge' but I keep getting segmentation fault everytime I compile the program. This is the source code and I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // Detect pixels along the edges and corners
            if ((i == 0 || i == height - 1) && (j == 0 || j == width - 1))
            {
                // For pixels at the top-left corner
                if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                {
                    loop_parameter_2(i, j, 2, 2, height, width, image, i, j);
                }

                // For pixels at the top-right corner
                else if (i == 0 && j == width - 1)    
                {
                    loop_parameter_2(i, j - 1, 2, 2, height, width, image, i, j);
                }

                // For pixels at the buttom-left corner
                else if (i == height - 1 && j == 0)    
                {
                    loop_parameter_2(i - 1, j, 2, 2, height, width, image, i, j);
                }

                // For pixels at the buttom-right corner
                else if (i == height - 1 && j == width - 1)    
                {
                    loop_parameter_2(i - 1, j - 1, 2, 2, height, width, image, i, j);
                }

                // For pixels along the top edges
                else if (i == 0 && j > 0 && j < width - 1)
                {
                    loop_parameter_2(i, j - 1, 2, 3, height, width, image, i, j);
                }

                // For pixels along the buttom edges
                else if (i == height - 1 && j > 0 && j < width - 1)
                {
                    loop_parameter_2(i - 1, j - 1, 2, 3, height, width, image, i, j);
                }
                
                // For pixels along the left edges
                else if (j == 0 && i > 0 && i < height - 1)
                {
                    loop_parameter_2(i - 1, j, 3, 2, height, width, image, i, j);
                }
                
                // For pixels along the right edges
                else if (j == width - 1 && i > 0 && i < height - 1)
                {
                    loop_parameter_2(i - 1, j - 1, 3, 2, height, width, image, i, j);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                loop_parameter_2(i - 1, j - 1, 3, 3, height, width, image, i, j);
            }
        }
        
    }
    return;
}
```

and this is the 'loop_parameter_2' code:

```
void loop_parameter_2(int height, int width, int times_to_loop1, int times_to_loop2, int h, int w, RGBTRIPLE image[h][w], int i, int j)
{
    // Kernel for the x direction 
    int Gx[3][3] = {
        {-1, 0, 1},
        {-2, 0, 2},
        {-1, 0, 1}
    };

    // Kernel for the y direction
    int Gy[3][3] = {
        {-1, -2, -1},
        {0, 0, 0},
        {1, 2, 1}
    };

    int t1;
    int t2;
    // Detect pixels along the edges and corners
    if ((i == 0 || i == height - 1) && (j == 0 || j == width - 1))
    {
        // For pixels at the top-left corner
        if (i == 0 && j == 0)
        {
            t1 = 1;
            t2 = 1;
        }

        // For pixels at the top-right corner and top edges
        else if ((i == 0 && j == width - 1) || (i == 0 && j > 0 && j < width - 1))    
        {
            t1 = 1;
            t2 = 0;
        }

        // For pixels at the buttom-left corner and left edges
        else if ((i == height - 1 && j == 0) || (j == 0 && i > 0 && i < height - 1))    
        {
            t1 = 0;
            t2 = 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        t1 = 0;
        t2 = 0;
    }

    // Variables to store weighted sums
    int sumRGx = 0;
    int sumRGy = 0;
    int sumGGx = 0;
    int sumGGy = 0;
    int sumBGx = 0;
    int sumBGy = 0;
    for (int a = height; a < height + times_to_loop1; a++)
    {
        for (int b = width; b < width + times_to_loop2; b++)
        {
            // Weighted sums for the red channel
            sumRGx += (image[a][b].rgbtRed * Gx[t1][t2]);
            sumRGy += (image[a][b].rgbtRed * Gy[t1][t2]);

            // Weighted sums for the green channel
            sumGGx += (image[a][b].rgbtGreen * Gx[t1][t2]);
            sumGGy += (image[a][b].rgbtGreen * Gy[t1][t2]);

            // Weighted sums for the blue channel
            sumBGx+= (image[a][b].rgbtBlue * Gx[t1][t2]);
            sumBGy += (image[a][b].rgbtBlue * Gy[t1][t2]);

            t2++;
        }
        t2 = 0;
        t1++;
    }

    image[i][j].rgbtRed = sqrt(sumRGx * sumRGx + sumRGy * sumRGy);
    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sqrt(sumGGx * sumGGx + sumGGy * sumGGy);
    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sqrt(sumBGx * sumBGx + sumBGy * sumBGy);
}
```

I tried adding additional elements to the Gx and Gy kernels just in case they were stepping out of bounds but it still didn't work. Valgrind is able to handle seg fault and output an image but the image is so grainy and you can't see anything in the image.

Comment: Your line `if ((i == 0 || i == height - 1) && (j == 0 || j == width - 1))` should probably be using `||` in place of `&&`.  Whether that has anything to do with the crash is a separate discussion, but it could be.  At the moment, it only picks up the 4 corners, not the edges as the comments suggest.

Comment: In this call `loop_parameter_2(i, j, 2, 2, height, width, image, i, j);` the first argument is for `height` in this loop `for (int a = height; a < height + times_to_loop1; a++)` which can break the array bounds when the caller's `i == height - 1` and similarly for the width direction.

Comment: For a simple way to index into the arrays, see my answer: [CS50 - Issue with pset4 filter "blur"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61395136/5382650) It's for regular blur but the indexing will be similar for sobel.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] instead of two incomplete snippets of code.

Comment: @AllanWind Sorry, I didn't know about this 'minimal reproducible example' thing. I am a beginner and I think the naming in my code was all wrong but I was kinda lazy thinking about the names. But thanks, everyone for even looking at my code.  But as for the incompleteness of the code, can you please elaborate further as to what else I should add?

Comment: It's all good, buddy.  Good question usually means quick, good answers.  If you haven't check out the top right ? then Help Center and read a few of the asking articles.  It will help you get the most of out stackoverflow.

Comment: @SylvesterAdade Post the code that calls `edges()` - a [mcve].

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I don't really understand the main code that calls the edges function enough to write a minimal reproducible example as this problem is a pset  from cs50. Most of the code was already written for us and we were only asked to implement the filtering functions. But if you want to see it, give me a feedback so I can post it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
   struct {
      unsigned char rgbtRed, rgbtGreen, rgbtBlue;
   };
   unsigned char comps[3];
} RGBTRIPLE;

int main()
{
    RGBTRIPLE image[][5] = {
            { {{ 0, 0, 0 }}, {{ 0, 255, 0 }}, {{   0, 0, 0 }}, {{   0, 0, 0 }}, {{   0, 0, 0 }} },
            { {{ 0, 0, 0 }}, {{ 0, 255, 0 }}, {{   0, 0, 0 }}, {{   0, 0, 0 }}, {{   0, 0, 0 }} },
            { {{ 0, 0, 0 }}, {{ 0, 255, 0 }}, {{ 255, 0, 0 }}, {{ 255, 0, 0 }}, {{ 255, 0, 0 }} },
            { {{ 0, 0, 0 }}, {{ 0, 255, 0 }}, {{   0, 0, 0 }}, {{   0, 0, 0 }}, {{   0, 0, 0 }} },
            { {{ 0, 0, 0 }}, {{ 0, 255, 0 }}, {{   0, 0, 0 }}, {{   0, 0, 0 }}, {{   0, 0, 0 }} },
        };
    int height = sizeof(image) / sizeof(*image), width = sizeof(*image) / sizeof(**image);
    edges(height, width, image);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for (int comp_i = 0; comp_i < 3; ++comp_i) {
                printf("%3d ", image[y][x].comps[comp_i]);
            }
            printf("  ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and I didn’t get any segfault. Therefore it is caused by something else in your project.

However, the results of your algorithm are not correct at all. I noticed the 2 following errors, but fixing them does not solve everything:

- When applying a convolution, you must save the original image content, you can’t modify it in place, because each color value is computed using previous pixels.
- You should have given your `RGBTRIPLE` type definition. If it contains `unsigned char` values for example, you have to make sure that if you get a value above 255, you actually write a value of 255 (by default, only the remainder of a division by 256 is kept).

Anyway your code as to be refactored a lot. It can clearly improved. Use something like this instead:

```c
RGBTRIPLE sobel_on_pixel(int k_y1, int k_x1, int k_y2, int k_x2,
        int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int y, int x)
{
    // Kernels for the x and y directions
    int Gx[3][3] = {
        {-1, 0, 1},
        {-2, 0, 2},
        {-1, 0, 1}
    };
    int Gy[3][3] = {
        {-1, -2, -1},
        {0, 0, 0},
        {1, 2, 1}
    };

    RGBTRIPLE result;
    for (int comp_i = 0; comp_i < 3; ++comp_i)
    {
        // Variables to store weighted sums
        int sumX = 0, sumY = 0;
        for (int k_y = k_y1; k_y < k_y2; ++k_y)
        {
            for (int k_x = k_x1; k_x < k_x2; ++k_x)
            {
                int comp = image[y + k_y - 1][x + k_x - 1].comps[comp_i];
                sumX += comp * Gx[k_y][k_x];
                sumY += comp * Gy[k_y][k_x];
            }
        }
        int dist = (int)sqrt(sumX * sumX + sumY * sumY);
        result.comps[comp_i] = dist > 255 ? 255 : dist;
    }
    return result;
}

void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE image_copy[height][width];
    memcpy(image_copy, image, sizeof(image_copy));
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            int k_y1 = 0, k_x1 = 0, k_y2 = 3, k_x2 = 3;

            // Along edges and corners, we won’t apply the whole kernels
            if (y == 0) {
                ++k_y1;
            }
            if (y == height - 1) {
                --k_y2;
            }
            if (x == 0) {
                ++k_x1;
            }
            if (x == width - 1) {
                --k_x2;
            }

            image[y][x] = sobel_on_pixel(k_y1, k_x1, k_y2, k_x2, height, width, image_copy, y, x);
        }
    }
}
```